# mySql join average from a table where id in list of id's

Tags: mysql, join, average

I have the following query in some code that I have taken over from another dev and the performance is very poor since it has a lot of nested database calls.

I want to use joins instead so what I am looking to is "pseudoish" this.

```
SELECT * FROM keywords as kw
```

on keywords I want to join

```
SELECT round(avg(sv)) as avg 
FROM `keyword_sv` 
WHERE keyword_id IN Select id from keywords where keyword.name = kw.name
```

I hope this makes sense thanks in advance

Comment: so what do you want? everything from `keywords` including avg from `keyword_sv`?

Comment: Yes indeed but the avg from keyword_sv isnt just join on the the keyword_sv.keyword_id, the code gets a list of id's from keywords with this query  SELECT id FROM keywords WHERE keyword LIKE '$row[keyword]' and then he goes on to something like 

SELECT round(avg(sv)) as avg FROM `keyword_sv` WHERE keyword_id LIKE 1 OR keyword LIKE 2....

Comment: it's terrible :)

Comment: yea; hard to follow as-is; you will need to add some table definitions, even sample data to this question if you'd like to get anyone to bite.

Comment: Please add sample data for these two tables and your desired results. It's not at all clear what your data looks like and what you are after based purely on your psuedocode.